# nginx multi-domain certificate from Wosign

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl-certificate

I want to set WoSign certificate for nginx. It is working for my domain, but for subdomains get an error

```
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).
```

Can anyone help me??

P.S This is nginx conf file

```
#
worker_processes 2;

#
user nginx nginx;

#
pid {{ nginx_path_prefix }}/pids/nginx.pid;
error_log {{ nginx_path_prefix }}/logs/error.log;

#
events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

#
http {
#
log_format full_log '$remote_addr - $remote_user $request_time   $upstream_response_time '
                    '[$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent $request_body "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#
access_log  /opt/nginx/logs/access.log;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate {{ nginx_path_prefix }}/cert/{{ suffix }}.crt;
ssl_certificate_key {{ nginx_path_prefix }}/cert/{{ suffix }}.key;

#
include {{ nginx_path_prefix }}/conf/vhosts/*.conf;

# Deny access to any other host
server {
    server_name dropcryptor.com;  #default
    return 444;
}
```

}

Thanks